# undefined method for Queries:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, rspec

I am building some tests for a query from graphql, at a rails app, but i keep getting this error: "undefined method `AllUsers' for Queries:Module".
Im not sure, but i think it is related to the module. Can anyone help, me please?

- All Users Query

```html
module Queries
  class AllUsers < BaseQuery
    type [Types::UserType], null: false
    description 'Fetch all users'

    def resolve
      User.all
    end
  end
end
```

- All Users Rspec

```html
require 'rails_helper'


  RSpec.describe Queries::AllUsers type: :request do
    describe 'Query' do
      it 'Successfully returns all users' do
        post '/graphql', params: { query: }
        json = JSON.parse(response.body)
        data = json['data']['users']
        expect(data).to match_array [hash_including('id' => be_present, 'firstName' => be_present,
                                                    'lastName' => be_present, 'email' => be_present)]
      end
    end

    def query_user
      <<~GQL
        query{
            users{
            id
            firstName
            lastName
            email
            }
        }
      GQL
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you miss the comma?

Behind `Queries::AllUsers` need `,`

```rb
...

RSpec.describe Queries::AllUsers, type: :request do

...
```

Comment: Yes I did :( Thank you   (its always either a comma, or a "s" )

Comment: So you add the comma, and your error was just solved?

Comment: Basically yes, the missing comma was throwing an error that was preventing me to see other errors in the code

Comment: Ok, if my answer solved your error, Please accepted this as the best answer. : )